# Setting User based preferences in PHP using Cookies

Tags: html, css

I'm doing an assignment where I need to be able to change the color of ones log in page according to preference. Now I have been able to successfully do that BUT no matter what I do the color will not take up the whole page only around the FORM itself leaving the rest white, can you please tell me where I have made the mistake? Please see my coding below:

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Home Page</title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="profile">
<b id="welcome">Welcome : <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>

<b id="logout"><a href="logoff.php">Log Out</a></b>

<?php

   $red = "";
    $blue = "";
    $green = "";
    $gold = "";
    $silver = "";
    $purple = "";

    $hour = time() + 3600;


    if (isset($_POST['order']))
    {
        $color = $_POST['order'];
        $$color = " selected";
        setcookie("Free_cookies", $color, $hour);
    }

    else if(isset($_COOKIE['Free_cookies']))
    {
        $color = $_COOKIE['Free_cookies'];
        $$color = " selected";
    } 

    else
    {
        $color = "red";
        $red = " selected";
    }
    $red = "";
    $blue = "";
    $green = "";
    $gold = "";
    $silver = "";
    $purple = "";

    $hour = time() + 3600;

    // first check for a new value, and use it as well as saving it for next time
    if (isset($_POST['order']))
    {
        $color = $_POST['order'];
        $$color = " selected";
        setcookie("Free_cookies", $color, $hour);
    }
    // if there's no new value, THEN check for a previous value in a cookie
    else if(isset($_COOKIE['Free_cookies']))
    {
        $color = $_COOKIE['Free_cookies'];
        $$color = " selected";
    } 
    // otherwise default to red
    else
    {
        $color = "red";
        $red = " selected";
    }
?>




<form method='post' <?php echo "STYLE='background-color:".$color.";'";?> ><p id='txtorder'  >color: </p>

    <select name='order' id='order'>
        <option value="red" <?php echo $red; ?> >red</option>
        <option value="blue" <?php echo $blue; ?> >blue</option>
        <option value="green" <?php echo $green; ?> >green</option>
        <option value="gold" <?php echo $gold; ?> >gold</option>
        <option value="silver" <?php echo $silver; ?> >silver</option>
        <option value="purple" <?php echo $purple; ?> >purple</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='sort'/>


</form>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: style the page body, not just the form -this is a html\css question nothing to do with php

Comment: I have tried that and it still won't work. I tried creating a div class surrounding the whole thing & it would only stay around the form. I thought if I moved <?php echo "STYLE='background-color:".$color.";'";?> to the body div & style it that way but I get an unknown syntax error.

Comment: it does work in the body. you will have to move your php above your html (good practice anyway)

Comment: Ahh ok thanks @nogad!